# Windows Azure Media Services Apple HLS Streaming - No video plays only audio plays

Tags: azure, http-live-streaming, smooth-streaming

I am using Windows Azure Media Services to upload video files, encode, and then publish them.
I encode the files using Windows Azure Media Services Samples code, and I have found that when I use the code to convert ".mp4" files to Apple HLS, it does not function properly in iOS devices. Only audio plays and no video is seen. Whereas, if I use Windows Azure Media Services Portal to encode and publish files in HLS, they work perfectly fine on iOS devices(both audio and video plays)!

I have been banging my head on this for days now and would be really obliged is somebody could guide me on the encoding process (through code)?

This is what I have till now!

```
static IAsset CreateEncodingJob(IAsset asset)
    {


        // Declare a new job.
        IJob job = _context.Jobs.Create("My encoding job");
        // Get a media processor reference, and pass to it the name of the 
        // processor to use for the specific task.
        IMediaProcessor processor = GetLatestMediaProcessorByName("Windows Azure Media Encoder");
        // Create a task with the encoding details, using a string preset.
        ITask task = job.Tasks.AddNew("My encoding task",
            processor,
            "H264 Broadband SD 4x3", 
            TaskOptions.ProtectedConfiguration);
        // Specify the input asset to be encoded.
        task.InputAssets.Add(asset);
        // Add an output asset to contain the results of the job. 
        // This output is specified as AssetCreationOptions.None, which 
        // means the output asset is in the clear (unencrypted). 
        task.OutputAssets.AddNew("Output MP4 asset",
            true,
            AssetCreationOptions.None);

        // Launch the job. 
        job.Submit();

        // Checks job progress and prints to the console. 
        CheckJobProgress(job.Id);

        // Get an updated job reference, after waiting for the job 
        // on the thread in the CheckJobProgress method.
        job = GetJob(job.Id);

        // Get a reference to the output asset from the job.
        IAsset outputAsset = job.OutputMediaAssets[0];


        return outputAsset;


    }


 static IAsset CreateMp4ToSmoothJob(IAsset asset)
    {

        // Read the encryption configuration data into a string. 
        string configuration = File.ReadAllText(Path.GetFullPath(_configFilePath + @"\MediaPackager_MP4ToSmooth.xml"));



        //Publish the asset.
        //GetStreamingOriginLocatorformp4(asset.Id);


        // Declare a new job.
        IJob job = _context.Jobs.Create("My MP4 to Smooth job");
        // Get a media processor reference, and pass to it the name of the 
        // processor to use for the specific task.
        IMediaProcessor processor = GetLatestMediaProcessorByName("Windows Azure Media Packager");

        // Create a task with the encoding details, using a configuration file. Specify 
        // the use of protected configuration, which encrypts sensitive config data.
        ITask task = job.Tasks.AddNew("My Mp4 to Smooth Task",
            processor,
            configuration,
            TaskOptions.ProtectedConfiguration);
        // Specify the input asset to be encoded.
        task.InputAssets.Add(asset);
        // Add an output asset to contain the results of the job.
        task.OutputAssets.AddNew("Output Smooth asset",
            true,
            AssetCreationOptions.None);

        // Launch the job. 
        job.Submit();

        // Checks job progress and prints to the console. 
        CheckJobProgress(job.Id);


        job = GetJob(job.Id);
        IAsset outputAsset = job.OutputMediaAssets[0];

        // Optionally download the output to the local machine.
        //DownloadAssetToLocal(job.Id, _outputIsmFolder);

        return outputAsset;
    }

    // Shows how to encode from smooth streaming to Apple HLS format.
    static IAsset CreateSmoothToHlsJob(IAsset outputSmoothAsset)
    {
        // Read the encryption configuration data into a string. 
        string configuration = File.ReadAllText(Path.GetFullPath(_configFilePath + @"\MediaPackager_SmoothToHLS.xml"));


        //var getismfile = from p in outputSmoothAsset.Files
        //                 where p.Name.EndsWith(".ism")
        //                 select p;

        //IAssetFile manifestFile = getismfile.First();

        //manifestFile.IsPrimary = true;

        var ismAssetFiles = outputSmoothAsset.AssetFiles.ToList().Where(f => f.Name.EndsWith(".ism", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).ToArray();

        if (ismAssetFiles.Count() != 1)
            throw new ArgumentException("The asset should have only one, .ism file");

        ismAssetFiles.First().IsPrimary = true;
        ismAssetFiles.First().Update();




        //Use the smooth asset as input asset


        IAsset asset = outputSmoothAsset;



        // Declare a new job.
        IJob job = _context.Jobs.Create("My Smooth Streams to Apple HLS job");
        // Get a media processor reference, and pass to it the name of the 
        // processor to use for the specific task.
        IMediaProcessor processor = GetMediaProcessor("Smooth Streams to HLS Task");

        // Create a task with the encoding details, using a configuration file.
        ITask task = job.Tasks.AddNew("My Smooth to HLS Task", processor, configuration, TaskOptions.ProtectedConfiguration);

        // Specify the input asset to be encoded.
        task.InputAssets.Add(asset);

        // Add an output asset to contain the results of the job.
        task.OutputAssets.AddNew("Output HLS asset", true, AssetCreationOptions.None);

        // Launch the job. 
        job.Submit();

        // Checks job progress and prints to the console. 
        CheckJobProgress(job.Id);

        // Optionally download the output to the local machine.
        //DownloadAssetToLocal(job.Id, outputFolder);

        job = GetJob(job.Id);
        IAsset outputAsset = job.OutputMediaAssets[0];

        return outputAsset;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to convert to an iOS compatible HLS, you have to use a Smooth Streaming Source, which would be the base for HLS. So your steps would be:

1. Convert your source to high quality H.264 (MP4)
2. Convert the result from step (1) into Microsoft Smooth Streaming
3. Convert the result from step (2) (the Smooth Streaming) into HLS

HLS is very similar to Microsoft Smooth Streaming. Thus it needs chunks of the source with different bitrates. Doing HLS conversion over MP4 will do nothing.

It is sad IMO that Microsoft provides such `explorative` features in the `management` portal. This leads to confused users. What does it do under the scene is exactly what I suggest to you - first gets a high quality MP4, then convert it to Microsoft Smooth streaming, then do the HLS over the Smooth Streaming. But the user things that HLS is performed over the MP4, which is totally wrong.

If we take a look at the [online documentation here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh973635.aspx), we will see that the task preset is named `Convert Smooth Streams to Apple HTTP Live Streams`. From where we have to figure out that the correct source for HLS is Microsoft Smooth Stream. And from my experience a good Smooth Stream can only be produced from a good H.264 source (MP4). If you try to convert a non H.264 source into a Smooth Stream, the result will most probably be an error.

You can experiment with the little tool [WaMediaWeb](https://github.com/astaykov/WaMediaWeb) (source on github with continuous delivery to Azure WebSites), here live: http://wamediaweb.azurewebsites.net/ - just provide your Media Account and Key. Take a look at the [readme on GitHub](https://github.com/astaykov/WaMediaWeb/blob/master/Readme.markdown) for some specifics, such as what source produces what result.

By the way, you can stack tasks in a single job, to avoid constant looking for job result. The method `task.OutputAssets.AddNew(...)` actually returns an IAsset, which you can use as an InputAsset for another task, and add that task to the same job. If you look at the example it does this at some point. It also does job well on creating HLS streams, tested on iOS with iPad2 and iPhone 4.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But I have found the solution for myself. I was not using the Windows Azure Media Encoder to convert my mp4 file into various bit rates for smooth streaming. I was rather using the Windows Azure Media Packager to convert my mp4 into smooth streaming which was converting into its native bit rate format (and not into various other bit rates). And also I would stack my tasks according to your suggestion!